# Convert dataframe / .csv to comma delimited .txt file

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, txt

Does anyone know how to easily convert a .csv / or a dataframe (inserted from that .csv into R) to a comma delimited .txt file?
For my analysis / the package to work I need a format like this:

**cell1, cell2, cell3, ...**

So comma then space between every cell of every row in my dataset.

In R I've tried:

```
write.table(df,"df.txt",sep=", ", na = "",row.names=FALSE, col.names = FALSE, append = FALSE)
```

However, the output looks like this:

**"cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "", "", "",**

First of all, the "" are an issue that I need to get rid of.
Secondly, every row has a different length, which means that the empty cells in shorter rows get the "" which is also a problem trying to run this in the package.

Other people using the package told me to use GNU emacs to convert it to the .txt file I need but I have no experience with this editor and it seems rather complicated to learn just for the conversion of this one (big) file

Cheers!

Edit:

Figured out how to get rid of the "" but still got the issue of the empty cells being separated by commas

```
write.table(test,"test2.txt",sep=", ", na = "", eol = "\r\n", row.names=FALSE, col.names = FALSE, append = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: No one can run this except you because the question has not provided the input.  Please follow the instructions on how to ask a question at the top of the [tag:R] tag home page.

Comment: Look at the manual page (`?write.table`) at the description of the `quote=` argument.